# how to make executeable file for android using phoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I have a web application and want to convert it to a native mobile application. I have converted all pages in html5 and then converted them into native mobile app for android through PhoneGap.

Now I want to build a .apk file. Can anyone help me on how to generate .apk file from a PhoneGap created hybrid app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create zip file in that put your all HTML files, JS files, CSS files with config.xml and plugin.xml in a particular format which is given by PhongapBuild. and send them within some minutes they wil send you APK file. No other files you need to create.
refer- https://build.phonegap.com/apps

Answer (score 3):

If you have created a PhoneGap application it should be some Html / JS.
You have to put this in an Android Eclipse project iwth some library.
You can find more information in the following link:
[Getting started phonegap Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way upload your code to github and use: https://build.phonegap.com/apps